# Talend - Retrieve SAP Table window doesn't open

Tags: talend, sap-data-dictionary

I have been retrieving SAP tables okay but am now having a problem.  We have a SAP connection set up and when I right-click and choose "Retrieve SAP table", a lock appears against the SAP connection, the list of tables expands and then contracts and nothing else happens.  If I choose one of the other options such as "Retrieve Business Content Extractor" the window opens up ok as normal.

Has anyone else had this issue?  I wasn't sure if the window is opening up minimised somewhere but if it is I can't locate it.

Comment: Is it a programming question? (what Stack Overflow is about)

Comment: Ah apologies i thought i would be able to find help on here for Talend - I'll see if I can find a more appropriate forum

Comment: my question was naive, just asking... You may ask programming questions on Talend here.